# using the .each() function doesn't allow me to use the .on() function

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, jquery-on

I would like to get some guidance on the use of `.each()` and `.on()`.

I am trying to remove the class `playing` from the element that contains them after they have ended their transition. However, on entering the code below, the console spews this out :

> jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: key.on is not a function

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 function removeTransition(e) {
      if (e.propertyName !== 'transform') return;
      e.target.classList.remove('playing');
  }


  function playSound(e){
    const audio = $(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
    const key = $(`div[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
    key.addClass('playing');
    if (!audio) return;
    audio[0].currentTime = 0;
    audio[0].play();
  }
      const keys = $("[class=key]");
    keys.each(key => key.on('transitionend', removeTransition));
    $('body').on("keydown", playSound);

})
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>JS Drum Kit</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div class="keys">
            <div data-key="65" class="key">
                <kbd>A</kbd>
                <span class="sound">clap</span>
            </div>
            <div data-key="83" class="key">
                <kbd>S</kbd>
                <span class="sound">hihat</span>
            </div>
            <div data-key="68" class="key">
                <kbd>D</kbd>
                <span class="sound">kick</span>
            </div>
            <div data-key="70" class="key">
                <kbd>F</kbd>
                <span class="sound">openhat</span>
            </div>
            <div data-key="71" class="key">
                <kbd>G</kbd>
                <span class="sound">boom</span>
            </div>
            <div data-key="72" class="key">
                <kbd>H</kbd>
                <span class="sound">ride</span>
            </div>
            <div data-key="74" class="key">
                <kbd>J</kbd>
                <span class="sound">snare</span>
            </div>
            <div data-key="75" class="key">
                <kbd>K</kbd>
                <span class="sound">tom</span>
            </div>
            <div data-key="76" class="key">
                <kbd>L</kbd>
                <span class="sound">tink</span>
            </div>

        </div>

        <audio data-key="65" src="sounds/clap.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="83" src="sounds/hihat.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="68" src="sounds/kick.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="70" src="sounds/openhat.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="71" src="sounds/boom.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="72" src="sounds/ride.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="74" src="sounds/snare.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="75" src="sounds/tom.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="76" src="sounds/tink.wav"></audio>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html{
    font-size: 12px;
    background:url(http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/95/30/yYO1JG.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
}

.keys{
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    min-height:100vh;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.key{
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin:1rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    padding:1rem .5rem;
    width:100px;
    text-align: center;
    color:black;
}

.playing {
    transform:scale(1.1);
    border-color:#9C2A00;
}
```

Comment: please post the full code

Comment: added the full code

Answer (score 1):

There are some things you need to change:

• The way you are assigning the each function was not working correctly

```
keys.each(function(){$(this).on('transitionend', removeTransition)});
```

• The reference to the property from the transition was not correct

```
if (e.originalEvent.propertyName !== 'transform') return;
```

• The way you were assigning the key value was creating some conflicts

```
const audio = $('audio[data-key="' + e.keyCode + '"]');
const key = $('div[data-key="' + e.keyCode + '"]');
```

• The most important, probably, **there was no transition in the CSS** so there was no callback on transitionend

```
transition: transform .5s ease;
```

---

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lq315c5p/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function removeTransition(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.propertyName !== 'transform') return;
    e.target.classList.remove('playing');
  }

  function playSound(e) {
    const audio = $('audio[data-key="' + e.keyCode + '"]');
    const key = $('div[data-key="' + e.keyCode + '"]');
    key.addClass('playing');
    if (!audio) return;
    audio[0].currentTime = 0;
    audio[0].play();
  }
  const keys = $("[class=key]");
  keys.each(function(){$(this).on('transitionend', removeTransition)});
  $('body').on("keydown", playSound);

})
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 12px;
  background: url(http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/95/30/yYO1JG.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
}

.keys {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.key {
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem .5rem;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

.playing {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  border-color: #9C2A00;
  transition: transform .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="keys">
  <div data-key="65" class="key">
    <kbd>A</kbd>
    <span class="sound">clap</span>
  </div>
  <div data-key="83" class="key">
    <kbd>S</kbd>
    <span class="sound">hihat</span>
  </div>
  <div data-key="68" class="key">
    <kbd>D</kbd>
    <span class="sound">kick</span>
  </div>
  <div data-key="70" class="key">
    <kbd>F</kbd>
    <span class="sound">openhat</span>
  </div>
  <div data-key="71" class="key">
    <kbd>G</kbd>
    <span class="sound">boom</span>
  </div>
  <div data-key="72" class="key">
    <kbd>H</kbd>
    <span class="sound">ride</span>
  </div>
  <div data-key="74" class="key">
    <kbd>J</kbd>
    <span class="sound">snare</span>
  </div>
  <div data-key="75" class="key">
    <kbd>K</kbd>
    <span class="sound">tom</span>
  </div>
  <div data-key="76" class="key">
    <kbd>L</kbd>
    <span class="sound">tink</span>
  </div>

</div>

<audio data-key="65" src="sounds/clap.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="83" src="sounds/hihat.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="68" src="sounds/kick.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="70" src="sounds/openhat.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="71" src="sounds/boom.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="72" src="sounds/ride.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="74" src="sounds/snare.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="75" src="sounds/tom.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="76" src="sounds/tink.wav"></audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function TestCtrl($) {
  $btns = $('.test');
  
  
  // the callback will be invoked with index and node
  $btns.each((index, node) => {
    $(node).click(() => console.log(index, node));
  })
}


jQuery(document).ready(TestCtrl);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="test">Test</button>
<button class="test">Test</button>
<button class="test">Test</button>
<button class="test">Test</button>
<button class="test">Test</button>
<button class="test">Test</button>
```

## Edit

Just wanna meet your code-case:

```js
function TestCtrl($) {
  let test = $('#Test');
  let $keys = $('.key');
  
  test.click(() => $keys.toggleClass('testing'));
  
  function onKeyTransitionEnd(event, $key, nodeIndex) {
    console.log("transitionend", nodeIndex);
  }
  
  $keys.each((i, node) => {
    let $node = $(node)
    .on(
      'transitionend', 
      e => onKeyTransitionEnd(e, $node, i)
    ); 
  });
}


jQuery(document).ready(TestCtrl);
```

```css
.keys {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.key {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: yellow;
  transition: 500ms all linear;
}

.key.testing {
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="Test">Test It</button>
<hr />

<div class="keys">
  <div class="key"></div>
  <div class="key"></div>
  <div class="key"></div>
  <div class="key"></div>
  <div class="key"></div>
  <div class="key"></div>
  <div class="key"></div>
  <div class="key"></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Huh? Im not quite sure.

Comment: you should click on the `blue button [Run code snippet]` and try by your self.

Comment: I am not to sure how that can be applied to my code.

Comment: sorry, but can you explain further?

Answer (score 0):

Try this , use `addEventListener` instead of `on`

```
keys.each(function(key) 
    {
    keys[key].addEventListener("transitionend", removeTransition);
    });
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 12px;
  background: url(http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/95/30/yYO1JG.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
}
.keys {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.key {
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem .5rem;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}
.playing {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  border-color: #9C2A00;
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>JS Drum Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="keys">
    <div data-key="65" class="key">
      <kbd>A</kbd>
      <span class="sound">clap</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="83" class="key">
      <kbd>S</kbd>
      <span class="sound">hihat</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="68" class="key">
      <kbd>D</kbd>
      <span class="sound">kick</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="70" class="key">
      <kbd>F</kbd>
      <span class="sound">openhat</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="71" class="key">
      <kbd>G</kbd>
      <span class="sound">boom</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="72" class="key">
      <kbd>H</kbd>
      <span class="sound">ride</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="74" class="key">
      <kbd>J</kbd>
      <span class="sound">snare</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="75" class="key">
      <kbd>K</kbd>
      <span class="sound">tom</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="76" class="key">
      <kbd>L</kbd>
      <span class="sound">tink</span>
    </div>

  </div>

  <audio data-key='65' src="sounds/clap.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="83" src="sounds/hihat.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="68" src="sounds/kick.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="70" src="sounds/openhat.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="71" src="sounds/boom.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="72" src="sounds/ride.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="74" src="sounds/snare.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="75" src="sounds/tom.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="76" src="sounds/tink.wav"></audio>


</body>

</html>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    function removeTransition(e) {
      if (e.propertyName !== 'transform') return;
      e.target.classList.remove('playing');
    }


    var key;

    function playSound(e) {
      const audio = $(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
      const key = $(`div[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
      key.addClass('playing');
      if (audio.length == 0) return;
      audio[0].currentTime = 0;
      audio[0].play();
    }
    $('body').on("keydown", playSound);
    const keys = $("[class=key]");
    keys.each(function(key) {
      keys[key].addEventListener("transitionend", removeTransition);
    });


  });
</script>
```

Comment: there's a transition that occurs when a key is pressed.

Comment: this is transitionend when the transition of player ends the transitionend triggers automatically and it calls the removeTransition function automatically

Comment: yeap but based on the input you gave, it doesn't execute when the transition ends.

Answer (score -1):

Key on this case is the element, not jQuery object. You need wrap it with jQuery object, like this.

```
keys.each((index, key) => $(key).on('transitionend', removeTransition));
```

Comment: by changing the code, the console outputs:
jquery.min.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: 
Object.defineProperty called on non-object(…)

Comment: `keys.each(key => ...)` => `keys.each((index, key) => ...)`

Comment: Oh yeah, jQuery gives key (index here) first, then value (key here), sorry about that. Updated my answer, should be correct now.

Comment: Nope. it still doesnt work, console doesn't give an error but it doesn't apply the removeTransition

Comment: Then your selector is wrong. Also, as I look at the selector, you should refactor it, `$("[class=key]")` could and should be written as `$('.key')`

Comment: $('.key') using this selector only selects one and not all the rest of the class which are labelled as key.

Comment: `$('.key')` selects all elements which has class `key`. https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/